# Como resolver o problema de acentuação no terminal?

Tags: c, c++, opengl

Estou escrevendo algumas strings em tela utilizando a biblioteca Opengl e algumas das palavras guardadas são palavras com acentuação, exemplo: `república checa`, onde a saída acaba sendo: `repblica checa` tem como resolver esse problema sem uso de biblioteca exterior? Não gostaria de usar a `#include <locale>` por medo de incompatibilidade entre sistemas windows ou linux, alguma solução?

Uma observação, utilizar a tabela ASCII não é uma opção viável.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez `std::wcout` (**[wchar_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wchar_t/)**) resolva o seu problema

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::wcout << L"república" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

No windows pra funcionar conforme essa [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2849040/1518921) é necessário iniciar pelo `cmd` com o `/u`

Outra coisa que pode tentar no caso do Windows é usar `_setmode` como descrito aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/tw4k6df8.aspx (este funcionou sem precisar aplicar o `/u`)

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"república\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado da aplicação C++ com Unicode]

> Testei no VisualStudio e no Mingw